# Values binded to TextBox not visible

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am setting the ng-bind attribute to a Textbox using JQuery so that the model value will display from an Angular Controller.  The model's value is bound to a select box so when it changes I should see a change in the textbox.

When the select box is changed nothing shows up visibly yet I can see the value attribute populated using F12 Developer Tools.

Why can I not see the value in the text box?  [Plunkr Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qc6ssrDV89kqmdh3jS06?p=preview)

```
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <p>This Simulates a Existing Input Box:
      <br/>
      <input id="originalSPTexbox" type="text" />
    </p>

    <hr/>

    <p>
      This dropdown contains project names found in search results.

    </p>
    <select ng-model="value" ng-change='ProjectSelected(value.RefinableString00)' ng-options="p.RefinableString00 for p in SearchResults track by p.RefinableString00">
      <option>-- Project --</option>
    </select>


    <p>
      This input box simply outputs the selected project:
      <br/>
      <input id="txt_Projects" style="width:95%" type="text" value='{{SelectedProj}}' />
    </p>

  </div>

  <script>
    $('body').attr('ng-app', 'changeExample');
    $('#originalSPTexbox').attr('ng-bind', 'SelectedProj')
     var data = '{<<json blob>>}';

    angular.module('changeExample', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
          var rawData = JSON.parse(data); // web  service call
          $scope.SearchResults = rawData.ResultRows;
          $scope.SelectedProj="Default Value";

          $scope.ProjectSelected = function(proj) {
            $scope.SelectedProj = proj;
            //$('input#originalSPTexbox').val(proj);
          };

        }
      ]);
  </script>
```

Comment: no it is not let me make sure

Comment: it is not working.  The textox on the top of the page is the one not working.

Comment: That is actually the point. I don't want to rely on that jquery in that method.  Like 42 does the binding for me.  The issue is that the Top textbox's value is populated as can be seen in the F12 Developer tools.  However no value can be seen with the naked eye.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the binding. Instead of adding ng-bind attribute via jquery I added

```
$('#originalSPTexbox').attr('value', '{{SelectedProj}}').
```

[New working Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/iIjISO1VwLfMgu3LqCOm?p=preview)